# Is there a way to get the console to ignore certain errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, null

Say I have an instance variable `@n`, and I'm calling `<%= @n.title %>` in my view.

If `@n` equals a valid record, then this will print normally. But if `@n` is blank or invalid, then the entire page will show an error message, because of this one little line.

Is there a way to get `@n.title` to just print nil if `@n` is nil or invalid?

I'm looking for a way to do this without conditional statements. For example, if I wanted to print

```
<%= @v1.title %>,<%= @v2.title %>,<%= @v3.title %>,<%= @v4.title %>,
```

if I wanted to use conditionals to print without errors, it would require 12 lines of code:

```
<% if @v1 %>
  <%= @v1.title %>,
<% end %>
<% if @v2 %>
  <%= @v2.title %>,
<% end %>
<% elsif @v3 %>
  <%= @v3.title %>,
<% end %>
<% elsif @v4 %>
  <%= @v4.title %>,
<% end %>
```

It seems a shame to use 12 lines on this. It would be nice to be able to accomplish the error-handling right when printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally do this easily with the `try()` method.  I use it all the time.

```
 <%= @n.try( :title ) %>
```

That will return `nil` if `@n` is `nil` or if the `title` method doesn't exist on `@n`.

You can also chain them together like this:

```
 @n.try( :title ).try( :to_s )
```

Or even use it on a hash:

```
 @n.try( :[], 'name' )  # Which is the same as @n['name']
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

**EDIT (Jan 11, 2016)**

You can now use the "safe navigation operator" as of [Ruby 2.3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released).

```
 @n&.title&.to_s
```

As well as the `Array#dig` and `Hash#dig` methods introduced in [Ruby 2.3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released).

```
 hash = { 'name' => 'bob' }
 hash.dig( 'name' )  # Which is the safe way to do hash['name']
```

Comment: Can you use this with links? For example, with `<%=link_to @n.try( :title), raze_path%>`, if `@n` is nil, then instead of printing nothing, the url output of `raze_path` will be printed. Can I get links to print nothing too?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logic to your view that differentiates between development (where some errors can be ignored) and production environments (where errors should cause your app to fail in an obvious and ugly manner). Ruby's `nil` has a "falsey" nature, so you can use that concept to your benefit as well.

```
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <% if @n %>
    <%= @n.title %>
  <% else %>
    <%= nil %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= @n.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this without conditional statements?

Comment: Well, not setting `@n` in the first place is "wrong," so I'm not sure your expectations are entirely realistic here. If you don't want to use conditionals, then make sure to set your fields properly in the controller. I'm not sure concise code is your first priority in this case. You can also make my code more succinct by combining the test for the environment with the test for the presence of `@n`, which further saves a couple of lines.